# How to override/ bypass a mock decorator in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Most of our external services are mocked for testing. Now I built test cases for the external services (Stripe in the example) and I would like to use the actual methods for only those tests. I could just decorate all the other tests, but those are a lot of tests and the likelihood of errors high. Also the mocks are done in our test runner, so they cascade though to all the tests. This is our runner function (it is decorated with a lot of similar mocks, reduced it to the minimal reproducible example)

```
@mock.patch('services.Stripe.sync_customers', side_effect=mock_sync_customers)
def run_tests(self, test_labels, extra_tests=None, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests, **kwargs)
```

This is the test case where I would like to use the actual methods instead of the mocks:

```
def test_customers(self):
    Company.objects.create(**customer_data) # This should invoke the actual API calls
```

Is there a way to exclude this or overwrite the mocks with the actual methods cleanly? I tried overriding it with a similar decorator as on the `run_tests`, which didn't work because the function on the `Stripe` class is not callable. I tried mocking the entire class, which also didn't work.

Comment: As you need a list of cases that will or will not run, what about to have a parameter in decorator to define if it is elegible to run or not?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So like a tag, which I would check for in the mock function? @MauroBaraldi

Comment: yes, exactly this!

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I don't think this is actually possible as the mock function doesn't get the tags and is a class function.

Comment: I tried `mock.patch.stopall()` but not even that could stop the decorators from working...

Comment: I believe that the solution to deactivate/activate mock (the decorator indeed in this case) could be harder and an over engineering. I would think in change the mock usage to context switch, and the decorator says if use or not the mock (the approach I've suggested before).

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Could you show this in code as an answer on this question?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was wrong, and it could not be done this way.